# Getting Selenium Exception: org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException:

Tags: selenium, devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException:

Network Request and Response

Comment: you should elaborate more your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please also provide the full code